# Double-hitch longboard

Tags: equipment, longboarding

My friend just got a new longboard, and he says it's "double hitched." When I Google double hitched longboard, it comes up with nothing familiar. His longboard turns extremely well, and I'm wondering what the actual name is. BTW His trucks are longer on the inside.

Answer (score 1):

**Double hitch** trucks are used in competitive longboarding (yes there is such a thing). They give the board a larger turn range, giving the rider the ability to make hairpin turns at higher speeds than your standard Thunder trucks. I only know them by that name but I imagine every company has their own name for them. Those are high quality trucks.